# What is the best way to use Eigen lazy evalution to multiply each row of an Nx3 matrix by a different 3x3 rotation matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

Pretty much the title. I'm trying to think up a good way to formulate this without creating any temporaries so I can actually make use of Eigen's speediness. The best I could come up with is this formulation:

[image: Matrix stuff]

Essentially, I end up with a `3nx3n` matrix being multiplied by a `3nxn` matrix, and I end up with a `3nxn` matrix of the transformed coordinates. Is this the most efficient approach? I don't love that there is the extra overhead (both performance and memory-wise) of constructing these full matrices.

Is there a way to maybe use an `Eigen::Map` on a contiguous set of data, e.g. `[a0, b0, c0, d0, e0, f0, g0, h0, i0, a1, b1, c1, d1,...]`, and have it behave like the sparse matrix below?

Additionally, if my above approach is the most sensible way, is there an efficient way to collapse the resulting matrix into a non-sparse `3xN` matrix of the results?

Comment: It's like instead of doing N separate multiplications of N pairs of numbers, you shove them into two NxN diagonal matrices and do a matrix multiplication. You can do that, but why?

Comment: My understanding is that `Eigen` does enough optimizations under the hood to make this preferable to a for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work the way you hope. The main issue is that for a dense matrix format, you would vastly increase the number of operations -- most of them being zero -- while for sparse matrix products, Eigen doesn't have a block-diagonal sparse format (though [we can build one if we want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213453/eigen-inverse-sparse-matrix-took-abnormal-long-time/76237818#76237818).

Instead, Eigen can optimize well for small fixed-size matrices or blocks of larger matrices. It is much better to use something like `Matrix3f` or `Matrix3Xf` than a `MatrixXf` that happens to be size 3 in one or both dimensions at runtime.

Therefore a good choice is to do something like this:

```cpp
    int rotation_count = ...;
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf rotations = Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Random(3, rotation_count * 3);
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf positions = Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Random(3, rotation_count);
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf out(3, rotation_count);
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < rotation_count; ++i)
        out.col(i).noalias() =
              rotations.middleCols<3>(i * 3) * positions.col(i);
```

Note two points in particular:

1. The number of rows is fixed instead of the number of columns. With Eigen's column-major matrix format, this means `middleCols` refers to a consecutive 3x3 segment instead of having a large stride from one column to the next.
2. We use the template overload of `middleCols` to create a block that carries the compile-time information that it is 3x3

We can further improve this by padding to 4x4 matrices. This wastes a bit of memory but it allows better vectorization since 4 floats fill one SSE register or 4 doubles fill one AVX register.

```cpp
    int rotation_count = ...;
    // With real data, keep the 4-th column and every 4-th row zero
    Eigen::Matrix4Xf rotations = Eigen::Matrix4Xf::Random(4, rotation_count * 4);
    Eigen::Matrix4Xf positions = Eigen::Matrix4Xf::Random(4, rotation_count);
    Eigen::Matrix4Xf out(4, rotation_count);
#   pragma omp parallel for
    for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < rotation_count; ++i)
        out.col(i).noalias() =
              rotations.middleCols<4>(i * 4) * positions.col(i);
```

On my system, the 3x3 implementation does 100,000 repetitions with 10,000 rotation matrices in 3.7 seconds and the 4x4 implementation takes 2,6 seconds. Make sure to compile with `-DNDEBUG` for production to remove the cost of assertions.

Alternatively you could try and get [Eigen's unsupported tensor module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html) to work for this but I'm not familiar with its use.

Comment: This is great! Would you expect the performance of this to be a worthwhile improvement over looping over individual 4x4 rotation matrices? As a side note, making things 4x4 is actually extra convenient because it makes it easier to swap in generalized transform matrices if that becomes necessary for me.

Comment: @Danny individual 4x4 are fine, too, no performance difference. I thought maybe they might even be faster on SSE hardware since the compiler has an easier time knowing that the structure is 16 byte aligned but GCC can figure it out for segments, too.

Comment: Understood! Then there's really no compelling reason for me to shove everything into one giant matrix then? The logic for looping over the columns is helpful, though.

One more question, if I did want to sort my data in row major order, would using something like `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor>` eliminate concerns about performance hits from cache-locality?